# post request in Next.js is not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js, react-query

In Next.js I'm trying to POST data in MongoDB using `react-query` and `useMutation`

I've structured my **endpoints** in `api/users/index.js`

```
import connectDB from "../../../db/connectDB";
import {getUsers, postUser, updateUser, deleteUser} from "../../../db/controllers/AddedUserController";

/**
 * @param {import('next').NextApiRequest} req
 * @param {import('next').NextApiResponse} res
 */

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    await connectDB().catch(() => res.status(405).json({error: "Connection Error"}))

    const {method} = req

    switch(method) {
        case "GET":
            await getUsers(req, res)
            break;
        case "POST":
            await postUser(req, res)
            break;
        case "PUT":
            await updateUser(req, res)
            break;
        case "DELETE":
            await deleteUser(req, res)
            break;
        default:
            res.setHeader("Allow", ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"])
            res.status(405).end(`Method ${method} not allowed`)
    }
}
```

So if the **method** equals to *POST* it calls this endpoint in `db/controllers/AddedUserController.js`

```
/*** POST http://localhost:3000/api/users ***/
export async function postUser(req, res) {
    try {
        const {formData} = req.body
        console.log("API", formData)
        if(!formData || formData === undefined) return res.status(404).json({error: "Form data not provided"})

        await AddedUser.create(formData, function(err, data){
            return res.status(200).json(data)
        });

    } catch(error) {
        res.status(404).json(error)
    }
}
```

Finally I call this endpoint with this helper function

```
/*** POST new user ***/
export const addUser = async (formData) => {

    const Options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    }

    try {
        const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/api/users`, Options)
        const json = await response.json()
        
        return json

    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
        return error
    }
}
```

Then in my `AddingForm.js` component I call the helper function using `useMutation`

```
/*** components ***/
import {Button, InputGroup} from "../index";

import {useMutation} from "react-query";
import {addUser} from "../../../utils/helpers/helper";
import {useState} from "react";

const AddingForm = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("")
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("")

    const addMutation = useMutation(addUser)

    const newUser = async (e, formData) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        await addMutation.mutate(formData)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => newUser(e, {name, email})}>
                <InputGroup
                    label="Name"
                    name="name"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                />
                <InputGroup
                    label="Email"
                    name="email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />

                <Button className="bg-gray-200" type="submit">Aggiungi</Button>

            </form>
        </>
    )
}

export default AddingForm;
```

But I got a 404 error with the message *"Form data not provided"* from `db/controllers/AddedUserController.js`

`if(!formData || formData === undefined) return res.status(404).json({error: "Form data not provided"})`

Why is this happening??

Comment: Try `onSubmit={newUser}` & `addMutation.mutate(e.target)`

Comment: I've tried but it brings me back this error `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`